# Can't connect to AFP shares with 10.10.4

Tags: macos, mac-mini, sharing, afp

I just updated the Mac Mini that I use as a file server to the 10.10.4 and the Server App to 4.1.3. After I updated I can't connect anymore to the AFP share that I see in the Finder sidebar on the client, a MacBook Pro.

If I restart the sharing service in the Server App, the connection is successful. After a while, if I click again on the Mac Mini in the MBP Finder sidebar, it says "Connecting..." and then "Connection failed".

The web server on the Mac Mini doesn't respond either. I can't connect either with the "Screen Sharing" button and sometimes it just disappears from the sidebar.

On the MBP when the sharing connection fails it says:

```
14/07/15 14:10:23,438 sharingd[174]: SDSharePointBrowser::handleOpenCallBack returned 65
```

or:

```
14/07/15 15:14:36,418 NetAuthSysAgent[318]: DNSAddressResolver:Resolve CFNetServiceResolveWithTimeout failed
14/07/15 15:14:36,418 NetAuthSysAgent[318]: ERROR: AFP_GetServerInfo - connect failed 64
14/07/15 15:14:36,419 sharingd[179]: SDSharePointBrowser::handleOpenCallBack returned 64
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure this is exactly related to the question at hand, but it might help some with this issue.

> TL;DR: make sure your machine does not include `.` or `\`

First. back in OSX 10.9.x Apple changed the default file share service from AFP to SMB2, meaning if you use Finder to connect to a machines file share the machine will try SMB then it *should* try AFP if SMB fails.

I have just spend far too long looking at Wireshark conversations between a 10.10.5 client and 10.11.3 file server to see what was going on and I think may have found the reason this sometimes fails for some users.

First a setup that seems to work:
The server computer name is configured to `Computer 1` (note the space) in the `System Preferences > Sharing` pane. the netbios name for this machine is different but that does not come into play when connecting via Finder.

This results in Bonjour populating the client machine with a `computer 1` in the Shared section of the side bar. when you click on this shared item and then click the `Connect As...` button the following conversation happens between the client and server:

```
CLIENT: Tree Connect Request: \\computer 1._smb._tcp.local\IPC$
SERVER: STATUS_SUCCESS
CLIENT: Create Request File: srvsvc
...
CLIENT: Finder receives Directory listing
```

This works as expected, you click on the server enter your credentials and get access to the resources.

Now a configuration that does not work, same setup as above but this time the server name is changed to `computer.1` (using a dot instead of a space), this results in the following client server conversation:

```
CLIENT: Tree Connect Request: \\computer\.1._smb._tcp.local\IPC$
SERVER: STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_PATH
CLIENT: Tree Connect Request: \\<ip address>\IPC$
SERVER: STATUS_SUCCESS
CLIENT: Finder displays Connection Failed
```

There are two interesting parts to this:

1. The client escapes the `.` to `\.` causing the server to report back a bad path
2. As soon as the client notices the bad path error it tries connecting with the server IP address, that succeeds, but the client does not ask for a directory listing and displays the Connection Failed.
3. The connection does not fall back to AFP when SMB fails.

This seems like a bug in the OS's handling of invalid characters to the SMB protocol and proper fallback to either IP or AFP in the case of a failure.

I tested all of the US face special characters are the following characters are cause this problem: `.` (period) and `\` (backslash). Every other character seems to work fine (e.g. `!`, `@`, `%`, `?` ...) though I did not do an exhaustive check as the ascii character space.

Comment: Awesome! File sharing started working after I removed dot from the computer name. Thank you, that saved me from hours of debug!

Comment: Awesome! Finally able to connect all mac machines on the home network, after years of fruitless googling. This answer needs upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same problem with the "SDSharePointBrowser::handleOpenCallBack returned 65" error in the console. To fix it, I enabled, and then disabled, SMB and AFP file sharing in System Preferences. After a system restart the NAS then connects correctly via AFP.